# C++ smart pointer

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, virtual-functions

consider the following code:

```
class Base{

};

class Derived : public Base{

};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        std::unique_ptr<Base> b(new Derived());//1 // b is Base object but holds Derived pointer
        Base *b1 = new Derived();//Base obj points to Derived //3
        //std::unique_ptr<Base*> b(new Derived());//2
        return 0;
}
```

In the second statement(//2), I am getting compilation error, but if we consider syntax(//3), why I am getting this error, unique_ptr should be supplied pointer type instead of class type.

I am new to smart pointers in c++.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Are you including the header for `unique_ptr`? — `#include <memory>`

Comment: yes, i have included the header and also added std=c++11 in compiler options

Comment: @RonTang What does your statement ~"**Why do so, at least every time we use can write less a star.**" mean?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky,Sorry,I don't understand what I say.I decide to delete my last comment,

Answer (score 4):

`std::unique_ptr<T>` is a smart *pointer to `T`*; that is, it resembles `T*` but smarter.

Therefore, `std::unique_ptr<Base*>` is a smart *pointer to `Base*`*; that is, it resembles `Base**` but smarter.

Comment: Why `Base**` and not `Base*`?

Comment: @Igor: Because `Base**` is a pointer to `Base*`. And `Base*` is not a pointer to `Base*`: it's a pointer to `Base`.

Answer (score 1):

`std::unique_ptr` (and other pointers) take the type of the object it should point to, not of the pointer.

Think of it like this:

- Regular pointer: `T` becomes `T*`
- Unique pointer: `T` becomes `unique_ptr<T>`

Comment: if we use char** p = new char*[10]; std::unique_ptr<char*> u(p);, which means we have to follow the indirection by one level.

Comment: @user1254554 `T` in my above answer is generic, so if `T*` becomes `T**` then logically `T*` becomes `std::unique_ptr<T*>`.

Answer (score 1):

The class template `unique_ptr<T>` manages a pointer to an object of type T.

This is how `unique_ptr` is defined:

```
template<
    class T,
    class Deleter = std::default_delete<T>
> class unique_ptr;
```

It should be given the type T.

So if you need a pointer to `Base`, you should give it type `Base`. If you give it `Base*`, it will become pointer to pointer to `Base`.

See more details here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr
or here http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr/

Comment: But you should explain why `T` should be `Base` rather than `Base*`.